# how to Forward email using independent soft dll

Tags: email, exchange-server, forward

Please let me know, how to forward a email from exchange server using independent soft dll.

I like to forward email without using "EWS".

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few months late, but they have an example on their website.

http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/forwardmessage.html